# Order by objects relation (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql

Have 2 tables for example:

**In 1st:** object & parent columns

```
object | parent 
-------+---------
object1| null       
object2| object1  
object3| null
```

**2nd has:** object & reference columns

```
object | reference
-------+---------
object1| null       
object2| null       
object3| object1
```

Need to query tables to order like following: parent is first, then - child(s), objects which have reference(s) to parent.

```
object1
object2
object3
```

Is it possible to do in one SQL query or need to sort manually in an array? Seems it is a classical task, probably solution already exists somewhere?

Comment: completely confused....you have two tables with object, parent in both tables?  Is the first table referencing the second table, or do you have a table for each object/parent pair (hope not the latter as it's sorta silly).

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand the question, even with the correction.  Could you elaborate a little on the relationships between the tables?

Comment: Does not matter: how to make such order at least for one table, will extend to second. Let's say all objects available in both tables under "object" column. To query all object from 1st need to call SELECT object FROM table1, form 2nd: SELECT object FROM table2 GROUP BY object. Edited source example for more clear understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following recursive query works:

```
WITH RECURSIVE tables(object, rank) AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT o.object, 1 AS rank FROM oref o
    WHERE o.ref IS NULL
    UNION
    SELECT o.object, t.rank + 1 AS rank
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT o.object, o.ref FROM oref o
            WHERE ref IS NOT NULL) o, tables t
    WHERE o.ref = t.object AND rank <= t.rank
),
ordered AS (
    SELECT * FROM tables
)
SELECT * FROM tables 
WHERE tables.rank = (SELECT MAX(rank) FROM ordered WHERE ordered.object = tables.object)
ORDER BY rank;
```

Any comments, questions, objections, propositions? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```sql
CREATE TABLE oparen (object varchar(10), parent varchar(10));
CREATE TABLE oref (object varchar(10), ref varchar(10));
INSERT INTO oparen VALUES
    ('object1',null),('object2','object1'),
    ('object3',null),('object4','object2');
INSERT INTO oref VALUES
    ('object1',null),('object2',null),('object3','object1'),
    ('object5','object6'),('object6','object1'),('object7','object4');

WITH hier AS (
    SELECT parent AS obj, 1 AS rank FROM oparen
     WHERE parent IS NOT NULL
    UNION
    SELECT object, 2 FROM oparen
     WHERE parent IS NOT NULL
    UNION
    SELECT object, 3 FROM oref
     WHERE ref IS NOT NULL),
allobj AS (
    SELECT object AS obj FROM oparen
    UNION
    SELECT object FROM oref)
SELECT a.obj, coalesce(h.rank, 4) AS rank
  FROM allobj a LEFT JOIN hier h ON a.obj = h.obj
 ORDER BY coalesce(h.rank, 4), a.obj;
```

**EDIT:** After the improved example in the answer below, the following query should do the trick:

```sql
WITH parents AS (
    SELECT parent AS obj, 1 AS rank FROM oparen
     WHERE parent IS NOT NULL
    ),
family AS (
    SELECT * FROM parents
    UNION ALL
    SELECT object, 2 FROM oparen op
     WHERE parent IS NOT NULL
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT obj FROM parents WHERE obj = op.object)
    ),
hier AS (
    SELECT * FROM family
    UNION ALL
    SELECT object AS obj, coalesce(f.rank + 2, 5) AS rank
      FROM oref LEFT JOIN family f ON oref.ref = f.obj
     WHERE ref IS NOT NULL
    ),
allobj AS (
    SELECT object AS obj FROM oparen
    UNION
    SELECT object FROM oref)
SELECT a.obj, h.rank AS rank
  FROM allobj a LEFT JOIN hier h ON a.obj = h.obj
 ORDER BY h.rank, a.obj;
```

Testbed creation in the top is updated according to the new requirements.

Comment: +1 That should do it. Consider `UNION ALL` for the first CTE.

Answer (score 0):

I inserted following data:

```
INSERT INTO oparen VALUES
    ('object1',null),('object2','object1'),('object3',null),('object4','object2');
INSERT INTO oref VALUES
    ('object1',null),('object2',null),('object3','object1'),('object5','object6'),('object6','object1');
```

Order is incorrect and object2 listed twice. DISTINCT on obj breaks the order also. Should go 6 then 5.

Comment: Very good. The more input we have initially, the easier for SO community is to provide you with a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, does not work: checked for another data and simplified to use and only by oref table content:

```
INSERT INTO oref VALUES
('object1',null),('object2',null),('object3','object1'),
('object5','object6'),('object6','object1'),('object7','object4'), ('object4','object5');

WITH family AS (
    SELECT object AS obj, 1 AS rank FROM oref
     WHERE ref IS NULL
    ),
hier AS (
    SELECT * FROM family
    UNION ALL
    SELECT object AS obj, coalesce(f.rank + 2, 5) AS rank
      FROM oref LEFT JOIN family f ON oref.ref = f.obj
     WHERE ref IS NOT NULL
    ),
allobj AS (
    SELECT object AS obj FROM oref)
SELECT a.obj, h.rank AS rank
  FROM allobj a
  LEFT JOIN hier h ON a.obj = h.obj
 ORDER BY h.rank, a.obj;
```

Think need to use recursive queries here. Will write and post here.